# Is there a sane way to stagger a cron job across 4 hosts with Ansible?

Tags: deployment, ansible

I've been experimenting with writing playbooks for a few days and I'm writing a playbook to deploy an application right now. It's possible that I may be discovering it's not the right tool for the job.

The application is deployed HA across 4 systems on 2 sites and has a worst case SLA of 1 hour. That's being accomplished with a staggered cron that runs every 15 minutes. i.e. s1 runs at 0, s2 runs at 30 s3 runs at 15, ...

I've looked through all kinds of looping and cron and other modules that Ansible supports and can't really find a way that it supports incrementing an integer by 15 as it moves across a list of hosts, and maybe that's a silly way of doing things.

The only communication that these 4 servers have with each other is a directory on a non-HA NFS share. So the reason I'm doing it as a 15 minute staggered cron is to survive network partitions and the death of the NFS connection.

My other thoughts are ... I can just bite the bullet, make it a */15, and have an architecture that relies on praying that NFS never dies which would make writing the Ansible playbook trivial. I'm also considering deploying this with Fabric or a Bash script, it's just that the process for getting implementation plans approved, and for making changes by following them is very heavy, and I just want to simplify the steps someone has to take late at night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

You could use `host_vars` or `group_vars`, either in separate files, or directly in the inventory.
I will try to produce a simple example, that fits your description, using only the inventory file (and the playbook that applies the cron):

```
[site1]
host1 cron_restart_minute=0
host2 cron_restart_minute=30
host3 cron_restart_minute=15
host4 cron_restart_minute=45

[site2]
host5 cron_restart_minute=0
host6 cron_restart_minute=30
host7 cron_restart_minute=15
host8 cron_restart_minute=45
```

This uses host variables, you could also create other groups and use group variables, if the repetition became a problem.

In a playbook or role, you can simply refer to the variable.
On the same host:

```
- name: Configure the cron job
  cron:
    # your other options
    minute: "{{ cron_restart_minute }}"
```

On another host, you can access other hosts variables like so:
`hostvars[host2].cron_restart_minute`

## Solution 2

If you want a more dynamic solution, for example because you keep adding and removing hosts, you could set a variable in a task using `register` or `set_fact`, and calculate, for example by the number of hosts in the only group that the current host is in.

Example:

```
- name: Set fact for cron_restart_minute
  set_fact:
    cron_restart_minute: "{{ 60 / groups[group_names[0]].length * (1 + groups[group_names[0]].index(inventory_hostname)) | int }}"
```

I have not tested this expression, but I am confident that it works. It's Python / Jinja2. `group_names` is a 1 element array, given above inventory, since no host is in two groups at the same time. `groups` contains all hosts in a group, and then we find its length or the index of the current host by its `inventory_hostname` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`).

Links to relevant docs:
[Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)
[Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables), specifically [this part](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables).

Comment: You got it, I was discussing this with some coworkers at lunch and someone came up with the host vars solution, which I think is the correct level of abstraction for this particular project. I've been playing around with it and I'm pretty excited by how well it works. Thanks!